# Facing issue on onChange function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

facing issue during getting target value in this case i can't be able to add the value. Whereas with same code some other places it is working fine. Please explain about expected scanarios. here is my code

```
<input type="text" value={filterEventValue} name='filterEventValue' autocomplete="off" onChange={ this.filterEventUsers} />


 filterEventUsers = (e) => {
        console.log("e ::", e.target);
    }
```

When I am typing inside text field key is is not being typed inside field.
outPut:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the whole component, and also the errors ?

Comment: try console.log(e.target.value) and see what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should keep the input value in the state, and update it when typing:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { filterEventValue: '' };
}

filterEventUsers = (e) => {
  console.log("e ::", e.target);
  this.setState({ filterEventValue: e.target.value });
}

render() {
   return (
    <input type="text" value={filterEventValue} name='filterEventValue'  
      autocomplete="off" onChange={this.filterEventUsers.bind(this)} />
   )
}
```